# Load multiple files into mysql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql query called load data and it as follows:

Load data infile $filename into table....

I have a text file with a list of filenames (250,000 filenames)

I need a php script that will allow me to pass these filenames into mysql query instead of me adding the filenames 250 000 times.

Is there an easy way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   <?php

        $file = '/path/to/your_file.txt';
        $file_content = file_get_contents($file);
        $names = explode("\n", $file_content);
        foreach($names as $value)
        {

            $sql='INSERT INTO table VALUES('.$value.')';
            $rec_insert = mysql_query( $sql_statemanet);

            if(! $rec_insert )
            {
                 die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error()); 
            }
       }
   ?>
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

- If the files are on the server, I'd suggest you running a local script to load them to your database.
- If they're not, you could load them through FTP and use (again) a local script.
- If you have no access to store files on the server and/or not enough rights to run a script locally, then I think your best solution is:

  1. Zip all files into a single file
  2. Create a script to read this file, unzip it and save each file on your database.

Have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-read.php), it may be your start point! ;)